# FormulaArray commando is not working on VBA Execution Code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Basically I set up a formula en Excel which then I copied into VBA, however this is an array formula:

```
{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(('BD MXN'!$J$2:$J$5893="A")*('BD MXN'!$X$2:$X$5893='Acum MXN'!Q2)*('BD MXN'!$Q$2:$Q$5893='Acum MXN'!O2)*('BD MXN'!$I$2:$I$5893="REAL")*('BD MXN'!$W$2:$W$5893='Acum MXN'!P2)*('BD MXN'!$O$2:$O$5893='Acum MXN'!A2),'BD MXN'!$A$2:$A$5893),'BD MXN'!$A$2:$A$5893)>0))}_
```

What it does is to count unique values from another sheet considering various criteria. The formula works great if I do it on my own, however once I add it to the code it doesn't work. My code is the following:

```
Range("R2:R" & last).FormulaArray = "=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(('BD MXN'!$J$2:$J$" 
& Final & "=""A"")*('BD MXN'!$X$2:$X$" & Final & "='Acum MXN'!Q2)*('BD 
MXN'!$Q$2:$Q$" & Final & "='Acum MXN'!O2)*('BD MXN'!$I$2:$I$" & Final & 
"=""REAL"")*('BD MXN'!$W$2:$W$" & Final & "='Acum MXN'!P2)*('BD MXN'!$O$2:$O$" & 
Final & "='Acum MXN'!A2),'BD MXN'!$A$2:$A$" & Final & "),'BD MXN'!$A$2:$A$" & 
Final & ")>0))"
```

The `Final` variable is just a last row value. I know the formula works because if I do the same code but with "Formula" instead of "FormulaArray", it will throw a #VALUE error on Excel, then I go back to the cell and press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER and it works, I do nothing to the formula.

If I leave the FormulaArray option, it doesn't even write anything, it's like skipping that line.

Comment: You want to put the formula using `FormulaArray` into the first cell `R2` then fill down.  What you are doing is akin to highlighting all the cells, putting the formula in the formula bar and hitting Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  It will fill the same formula into all the rows.  You want to enter the formula into the first cell as an array formula then fill down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Range.FormulaArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulaarray) property has a character limit of 255. Your string is 362 characters long, hence the error. To work around the character limit, you have to use placeholders that you will later fill with the correct string, like this:

```vb
Dim pp As String, Final As Long, last As Long

pp = "--(FREQUENCY(IF(('BD MXN'!$J$2:$J$" 
& Final & "=""A"")*('BD MXN'!$X$2:$X$" & Final & "='Acum MXN'!Q2)*('BD 
MXN'!$Q$2:$Q$" & Final & "='Acum MXN'!O2)*('BD MXN'!$I$2:$I$" & Final & 
"=""REAL"")*('BD MXN'!$W$2:$W$" & Final & "='Acum MXN'!P2)*('BD MXN'!$O$2:$O$" & 
Final & "='Acum MXN'!A2),'BD MXN'!$A$2:$A$" & Final & "),'BD MXN'!$A$2:$A$" & 
Final & ")>0)"

With Range("R2:R" & last)
    .FormulaArray = "=SUM(PPP)"
    .Replace "PPP", pp
End With
```

Comment: I didn't know about the limit. However that solution didn't work. It just doesn't replace anything and leaves the range with the "=SUM(PPP)" formula in there. Any other suggestion to work around this?

Comment: @CarlosCasio, it works for me. I have tried it several times. You have to leave the VBA window and click inside on the sheet and the cells would update.

Comment: Oh my... that's true. Why is it necessary to leave the VBA window?. It worked tho, thank you for the solution!

Comment: @CarlosCasio, I am not really sure; I think it has to do with the fact that you are doing an in-place replace. I just make sure the range isn't selected beforehand, run my macro and then come back to see the results. That way it doesn't bother you.